# Transforming draws in Matlab from Gaussian mixture to uniform

Tags: matlab, random

Consider the following draws for a `2x1` vector in Matlab with a probability distribution that is a mixture of two Gaussian components.

```
P=10^3; %number draws
v=1;

%First component
mu_a = [0,0.5];
sigma_a = [v,0;0,v];

%Second component
mu_b = [0,8.2];
sigma_b = [v,0;0,v];


%Combine    
MU = [mu_a;mu_b];
SIGMA = cat(3,sigma_a,sigma_b);
w = ones(1,2)/2; %equal weight 0.5
obj = gmdistribution(MU,SIGMA,w);

%Draws
RV_temp = random(obj,P);%Px2

% Transform each component of RV_temp into a uniform in [0,1] by estimating the cdf.
RV1=ksdensity(RV_temp(:,1), RV_temp(:,1),'function', 'cdf');
RV2=ksdensity(RV_temp(:,2), RV_temp(:,2),'function', 'cdf');
```

Now, if we check whether `RV1` and `RV2` are uniformly distributed on `[0,1]` by doing

```
ecdf(RV1)
ecdf(RV2)
```

we can see that `RV1` is uniformly distributed on `[0,1]` (the empirical cdf is close to the 45 degree line) while `RV2` is not.

I don't understand why. It seems that the more distant are `mu_a(2)`and `mu_b(2)`, the worse the job done by `ksdensity` with a reasonable number of draws. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a mixture of N(0.5,v) and N(8.2,v) then the range of the generated data is larger than if you had expectation which were closer, like N(0,v) and N(0,v), as you have in the other dimension. Then you ask `ksdensity` to approximate a function using P points inside this range.

Like in standard linear interpolation, the denser the points the better approximation of the function (inside the range), this is the same case here. Thus in the N(0.5,v) and N(8.2,v) where the points are "sparse" (or sparser, is that a word?) the approximation is worse than in the N(0,v) and N(0,v) where the points are denser.

As a small side note, are there any reason that you do not apply `ksdensity` directly on the bivariate data? Also I cannot reproduce your comment where you say that `5e2`points are also good. Final comment, `1e3` is typically prefered over `10^3`.

Comment: Thanks. What do you intend by applying ksdensity to bivariate data? Do you know ways to force ksdensity to do a good job by varying the bandwidth?

Comment: Nothing, in particular, I was just curious why you split it into RV1 and RV2. As you anyway manually specify the points, I do not think that there is much of a difference. Regarding the bandwidth, then it is the size of the smoothening window, as you have too few points, you can try to increase the window, however, if you increase it too much it will also lower the peaks (at the mean value) and thus just introduce a new source of error. I got somewhat ok results at around bandwidth  = 1.

Comment: Is there any "rule of thumb" for the bandwidth which could help?

Comment: Well, as an ultimate upper bound, then it should be smaller than the distance between the peaks, otherwise, these will be turned into one peak. From that I would maybe put it like a tenth of the difference Then if the variance is small the separation is clearer and you can make the window a bit larger, and vice versa. It is the standard problem with smoothening, it looks better, but details are lost. So ask yourself, "if I turn this window into 1 value, are there details within this window, that I cannot afford to lose?"

Comment: Disclaimer: the question is not strictly correct as it is not a mean filter which is used, but it gives the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is simply about the number of samples you're using. For the first example, the means of the two Gaussians are relatively close, hence a thousand samples are enough to obtain a cdf really close the the U[0,1] cdf. On the second vector though, you have a higher difference, and need more samples. With 100000 samples, I obtained the following result:

### [image: Result with 100000 Samples]

With 1000 I obtained this:

[image: Result with 1000 Samples]

Which is clearly farther from the Uniform cdf function. Try to increase the number of samples to a million and check if the result is again getting closer.

Comment: I don't really understand this: is something specific of mixture? Because if I draw 500 samples from a bivariate normal with `mu=[0 10.678]`and `sigma=[v 0; 0 v]`, then `ksdensity`does a good job even if the two values in `mu`are quite distant.

Comment: None can help here?