# Command `gmdistribution` in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a question on the Matlab command `gmdistribution` to generate draws from mixtures of Gaussians.

Consider the following code to draw from a mixture of two bivariate normals

```
clear
rng default

P=10^4; %number draws

%First component (X1,X2)
v=1;
mu_a = [0,2];
sigma_a = [v,0;0,v];

%Second component (Y1,Y2)
mu_b = [0,4];  
sigma_b = [v,0;0,v]; 


MU = [mu_a;mu_b];
SIGMA = cat(3,sigma_a,sigma_b);
w = ones(1,2)/2; %equal weight 0.5
obj = gmdistribution(MU,SIGMA,w);


%Draws of the mixture (R1,R2)
R = random(obj,P);%nx2
```

We know that `(R1, R2)` may be correlated. Indeed, we can show that

```
cov(R1, R2)=1/4*cov(X1,Y2)+1/4*cov(X2, Y1)
```

because

```
cov(W1,W2)=E(W1*W2)-E(W1)E(W2)
=1/4E(X1*X2)+1/4E(X1*Y2)+1/4E(Y1* X2)+1/4E(Y1* Y2)
- [1/2E(X1)+1/2E(Y1)][1/2E(X2)+1/2E(Y2)]
=1/4 cov(X1, Y2)+1/4cov(Y1, X2)
```

However, if I check their correlation

```
corr(R(:,1), R(:,2))
```

I get almost zero `(0.0024)`

I checked for many other values of `MU, SIGMA`but I couldn't find any case with a correlation noticeably far from `0`. Is this just a case, or is that the command `gmdistribution` imposes `(X1,X2)` independent of `(Y1,Y2)`?

Comment: I have added my proof. Where do I write that `X` and `Y` are independent in my code?

Comment: No, in `sigma_a`you have the correlation between `X1,X2`. In `sigma_b`you have the correlation between `Y1,Y2`

Comment: erm, no, each covar matrix gives the correlation between x and y. Then you also see the main problem: Both distributions have the same mean in the x axis, therefore no trend can be found. Run it with the following settings: `mu_a = [0,0];
sigma_a = [v,0;0,v];
mu_b = [10,5];  
sigma_b = [v,0;0,v];` Then the following plot shows that one blob has its mean at 0,0, the other at 10,5: `[values, centers] = hist3(R,[51 51]);
imagesc(centers{:}, values.')` This will also lead to a high (~0.9) correlation value.

Comment: Thanks, then I think that I completely misunderstood the instructions on `gmdistribution`. Consider the example mathwork gives `mu = [1 2;-3 -5];
sigma = cat(3,[2 0;0 .5],[1 0;0 1]);
p = ones(1,2)/2;
obj = gmdistribution(mu,sigma,p);`

Comment: Can you tell me, which is the mean and the variance of the first component bivariate Gaussian, and which is the mean and the variance of the second component bivariate Gaussian?

Comment: My interpretation was that the mean and the variance of the first component are `[1 2]` and `[2 0; 0 0.5]` and   the mean and the variance of the second component are `[-3 -5]` and `[1 0; 0 1]`

Comment: So, with prob. 1/2 the rv `W` will "borrow" from the first component, and with prob. 1/2 the rv `W` will "borrow" from the second component.

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. If everything is clear now, you might consider deleting this question - ultimately the error was the result of just a small misunderstanding and I doubt anybody else will ever benefit from it. Which is a shame because the question is written really nicely ;)

Comment: @LeanderMoesinger I am sorry but if my interpretation is correct than I don't understand what you wrote above because I did exactly what mathwork does. First bivariate Gaussian for me is denoted by `X=(X1,X2)` with mean `mu_a` and variance-covariance matrix `sigma_a`. Second bivariate Gaussian for me is denoted  by `Y=(Y1,Y2)` with with mean `mu_b` and variance-covariance matrix `sigma_b`. In `mu_a` we find `E(X1)` `E(X2)`; In `sigma_a` we find `V(X1)` `V(X2)`, `cov(X1, X2)`. In `mu_b` we find `E(Y1)` `E(Y2)`; In `sigma_b` we find `V(Y1)` `V(Y2)`, `cov(Y1, Y2)`. That is what mathwork does.

Comment: I think what confused you are the subscripts 1,2 which in my notation are NOT referred to the two components of the mixture but to the two elements of each bivariate normal. The two components of the mixture in my notation are denoted as X,Y

Comment: Ah, that really confused me and it then  really just a matter of choosing the right means: The two means you chose are at 0,2 and 0,4. Therefore they are *above* each other and if you were to fit a line trough both means it would be vertical. This would imply a zero correlation. If you want a non-zero correlation X1 has to be != Y1 and X2 != Y2.

Comment: Thanks. If you could write a proper answer, also explaining better (possibly with some math) how the differences among the means can affect the final correlation, it would be extremely helpful. I am struggling with this. From your words, it seems that my derivation of the covariance `cov(W1, W2)` is wrong because it is not affected by the differences among the means. Where do the differences among the means come into play?

Comment: My question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45280267/transforming-draws-in-matlab-from-gaussian-mixture-to-uniform is also related, and you may be expert enough to answer it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can best illustrate the problem with a figure. To make the effect more visible, I decreased the variance of the both components from 1 to 0.2 (`v = 0.2`). If we then draw some realisations from the mixed model, we get the following scatterplot:

[image]

Each "blob" corresponds to one component, one with its centre at 0,2 the other at 0,4.

Now, on its basis the linear correlation coefficient tells us how much `W2` increases if `W1` increases by one. But as we can see there is no such trend in the realisations; If `W1` increases `W2` is not increasing or decreasing.

This due to both distributions having the same mean (0) in `W1`. If that is not the case, e.g `mu_a = [0,2];` and `mu_b = [2,5];` we get following plot:

[image]

Here it is clearly visible that if `W1` is high, chances are that `W2` is also very high. This leads to a high positive correlation of about 0.87. Summing this up, if either `mu_a(1) == mu_b(1)` or `mu_a(2) == mu_b(2)` then the correlation will be near zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In the last sentence, do you mean "if the average of X1=average Y1" or "if the average of X2=average Y2"?

Comment: Nice, thanks. Still, I need to understand how to show this analytically (showing that the correlation depends on the difference in the means), but I accept your answer as the math proof was not part of my question.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think that the math proof is correct; `cov(W1,W2)=E(W1*W2)-E(W1)E(W2)` would imply that the covariance only depends on the expected values without taking the realisations into consideration - but it has been some time since I last proofed anything in statistics so I might very well be wrong here.

Comment: I think it is wrong as well, because the difference in means (that you showed to be relevant in practice) doesn't seem to play a role in the proof. Thanks anyway